# Is this a drain fly?

Tags: drain, pest-control, pest, insect

The fly/moths have been increasing in my apartment. All my windows are closed. All summer there would occasionally be a few in my bathroom, and in the past week I sometimes come home to find tens of them in my kitchen and bathroom.

Picture is below, they don't appear to be drain flies from photos I've seen online. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because inside identification requests are off-topic.

Comment: And insect identification requests are also off-topic.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fuzzy picture, but it appears to be the type of moth that is the adult form of a "meal worm", called a "meal moth" or "Indian mealmoth". You likely have some opened bag of wheat or corn meal somewhere that you rarely use and it had meal worm eggs in it, which are almost microscopic and nearly impossible to remove in processing. Those eggs hatched into larvae, the "worm" stage, now those larvae have grown up and into their adult moth phase, where they only live a few days as they look to mate and make more babies.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianmeal_moth

Comment: Check your flour bins, Bisquick cornmeal etc. If not taken care of, the population can easily go exponential on you. Sift and check. If you've got the bugs in a product toss it. They'll eat most dry flour-like stuff. I switched to hermetically sealed plastic flour and cornmeal containers. That'll prevent spreading. Usually I find something, store contaminated, once or twice a year, but I cook a lot with flours and such.

Comment: Thanks so much! They look exactly like that. Really can't thank you enough, I'll be sure to look through my pantry and cabinets today.

Comment: Just to be clear, basically ALL packaged uncooked grains have the eggs in them, they are impossible to stop. But they are nearly microscopic and you never notice so long as you consume the product. But if you let it sit on the shelf too long they hatch and grow.